# Including a Wordpress header in a page that is under a non wordpress directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a single page that I would like to include my custom themed header for the page. The file structure to the header page is

`/wp-content/themes/COMPANYNAME-01/header.php`

and to my page is

`/company/site/lookup/index.php`

I have placed the following code into my php file

`include_once '/wp-content/themes/COMPANYNAME-01/header.php';`

But when I open it on the server I get the follow errors,

```
Warning: include_once(/wp-content/themes/COMPANYNAME-01/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/company/site/lookup/index.php on line 26

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/wp-content/themes/COMPANYNAME-01/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.2/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/company/site/lookup/index.php on line 26
```

I have seen previous posts about using the default startup function for wordpress but these apply if I am simply making wordpress a blog on my site. We are using wordpress to make the front end of the site and then making a custom web-app for the company itself. The problem is, the lookup is actually supposed to be public facing. If it is too difficult, we will end up having to recode a LOT of that controller and view.

Comment: You are including the file using the URI path from the URL, not the filesystem. You need to add `../../..` to your include or use the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your current set up but this is how we [load WP functions inside an external script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47049/12615):

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php' ); // adjust path if needed
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<?php
    wp_head();
?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <h1>External</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Probably your code should look like:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php' );
include_once '/wp-content/themes/COMPANYNAME-01/header.php';
```